# Displaying Images In Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to display my images in rows of 5 but for some reason the code adds an image at the end of the first row.

Is there an error with this code? If not, how do I change it to stop adding the extra image at the end of the first row.

Code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE gallery_number='$gallery_number'");

echo '<table width="960">';
$i = 0; //first, i set a counter 
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
//counter is zero then we are start new row  
    if ($i==0){
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    //here we creating normal cells <td></td>
    $image_name = $fetch['image_name'];
    $image_location = $fetch['image_location'];
    echo '<td>'.'<img src="'.$image_location.'" alt="'.$image_name.'"/>'.'</td>';   
    //there is a magic - if our counter is greater then 5 we set counter to zero and close tr tag  
    if ($i>5){
        $i=0;
        echo '</tr>';
    };  
    $i++; //$i = $i + 1 - counter + 1
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are beginning the `$i` count with `0`, so with your check, it will return 6 results.

```
if ($i>5){
    $i=0;
    echo '</tr>';
};
```

That should either be this:

```
if ($i>4){
    $i=0;
    echo '</tr>';
};
```

Or you could change your `$i` counter to start at `1` and reset to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't close TR. You are closing TR only if $i reaches 5, and you also don't open a new one. Check the result in the browser (Ctrl-U).

Your program should contain something like:

```
if ($i > 5) {
  echo("</tr><tr>");
  $i = 0;
}
```

It closes a full row and opens a new one. Also, you should open TR before the loop, and close after the loop. (Advanced task: eliminate empty TR pairs.)

Answer (score 0):

This code won't work for a couple of reasons.

First, think about how many times you are ACTUALLY creating `<td>`s. You start your counter, `$i` at `0`. You then only reset it after you reach `6`. You are looping too many times.

Second, with where you increment your counter, you will ONLY ever have 1 `<tr>` creation. This is because you reset your counter to `0`. You then immediately increase it to 1. This will prevent the next `<tr>`s from being created.